# How do i write PLSQL Query that will update the grant access for multiple tables at once |SQL Developer|

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a Scenario where I need to write a PLSQL Query to Grant permission to multiple table at once for Particular User Only for example : User_A

```
tbl_1
tbl_2
tbl_3
tbl_4
tbl_5
tbl_6
tbl_7
tbl_8
```

The above table as Read Acess only. Now I want to Provide write access , delete access to it

How do I achieve this Scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a cursor with `execute immediate` command to grant the desired privileges to `User_A` for all tables of your current schema(a schema other than `User_A`) :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  for c in
  (select 'grant insert, update, delete on '||t.table_name||' to User_A' as cmd
     from user_tables t
    order by t.table_name)
  loop 
    dbms_output.put_line(c.cmd);  
    execute immediate c.cmd;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Generally speaking it's better to have the DBMS_OUTPUT before the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. So if there's an error we know which statement failed rather than the last one to succeed

Comment: Is it really worth writing and then validating a 10 statement code block to avoid writing 8 grant statements. Besides, the above would grant rights to every table. You would need to pass a  multiple valued parameters for the tables and perhaps users, Then parse those out to individual values to generate the appropriate grant statements. Might be worth while if you anticipated doing it often.

Answer (score 0):

To literally answer your question, and run multiple grants at once, you need to use the [`CREATE SCHEMA`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-SCHEMA.html#GUID-2D154F9C-9E2B-4A09-B658-2EA5B99AC838) command.

The syntax is a bit tricky because you have to hard-code the name of the user running the statement.  And if one of the grants fails, they all fail, which may or may not be a good thing.  But compared to a PL/SQL script, or multiple SQL statements, this approach uses less code and is a bit faster.

```
create schema authorization USER_RUNNING_THE_QUERY
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_1 to test_user1
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_2 to test_user1
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_3 to test_user1
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_4 to test_user1
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_5 to test_user1
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_6 to test_user1
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_7 to test_user1
grant select, insert, update, delete on tbl_8 to test_user1;
```